# Recharts - Area Chart, spacing between data points

Tags: reactjs, recharts

[image: Graph Image]
I am trying to use Recharts to replicate the following graph in the attachment. Have checked via inspect that it is also using Recharts hence it is possible. However, when I try to replicate with similar data points, the smaller records are being pushed to the left end while the large records will take up most of the space. It might be using `<Area/>` under the 'type' https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Area but doesn't work and not familiar with D3. Appreciate for your assistance.